# Bilinear filtering of output image in Direct3D 11

Tags: image-resizing, direct3d11

I'd like to render something at one resolution, but display it in a window at another resolution (e.g. render the scene at 640x480 and stretch it to a 1024x768 window).

Simply resizing the window after creation allows this to work - however, the image is filtered using nearest-neighbor. Is there a way to change the filtering algorithm to e.g. bilinear?

Answer (score 3):

There's basically three approaches to this:

One approach is to use a Direct3D backbuffer that is always 640 x 480, but allow the DXGI `Present` to handle the scaling to some other window size (1024 x 768). In Direct3D 11.1 you can achieve this using `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1.Scaling` and set it `DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH`. On Windows phone 8 or Windows 10, you can use `DXGI_SCALING_ASPECT_RATIO_STRETCH` as well. In this case you don't have control over how the filtering is achieved, but it is mostly automatic.

> `DXGI_SCALING_ASPECT_RATIO_STRETCH` only works with CoreWindow and DirectComposition swapchains using `CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow` or `CreateSwapChainForComposition` (i.e. not classic Win32 windows using `CreateSwapChainForHwnd`). To know where in the output window the aspect-ratio preserved image is actually placed, see the code for DirectX Tool Kit's [Viewport::ComputeDisplayArea](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Viewport)

The other approach is to resize your backbuffer to match the output window, but then use texturing on a 'full-screen quad' to achieve the stretch. In this case, you have more direct control over the filtering used. See DirectX Tool Kit's [SpriteBatch](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SpriteBatch) and [D3D11_FILTER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476132.aspx).

Finally, you can do the resizing of the original image on the CPU. Here you have the most flexibility and control to do the resize, but the performance will be significantly slower. You can do a Resize with [WIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff973956.aspx) or [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) as well.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually trying to modify an existing application to do this. Can the second method be done by inserting some calls before and after rendering the entire scene?